# Angular 4 : how to pass an argument to a Service provided in a module file

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm calling to you for help on what method to use here : I have tested many things to solve my problem and I have at least 4 working solutions, but I don't know which one(s) would be the best and if some of them work only because of a side effect of something else I did and should not be used...

I couldn't find anything in the documentation to point me to one of these solutions (or another one)

**First, here's my situation** : I'm building an app that connects to an API for data and builds different sections, each containing dataviz.

I built the sections of the site to be modules, but they share a service named DataService (each of these modules will use the DataService to get and process the data).

My DataService needs a config file with a number of options that are specific to each section and stored in it's own folder.

So I need to provide DataService separately for each section, in the providers section of the module.ts file, and it seemed like good practice to avoid copying DataService to each module...

So the architecture of the files would be :

```
--Dashboard module
----data.service.ts
----Section1 module
------Section1 config file
----Section2 module
------Section2 config file
```

I tried multiple things that all seem to work in the section module file :

**Solution 1 : injection**

(I couldn't get the injection to work without quotation marks, even if I didn't see this anywhere)

Module file :

```
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import viewConfig from './view.config.json';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ ... ],
    declarations: [ ... ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'VIEW_CONFIG', useValue: viewConfig },
        DataService,
    ]})
   export class Section1Module { }
```

Section file :

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(@Inject('VIEW_CONFIG') private viewConfig : any) {}

}
```

<s>**Solution 2 : factory provider**</s>

***Not working after ng serve reboot (see update)***

<s>Inspired from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#factory-provider</s>

Module file :

```
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import viewConfig from './view.config.json';

export let VIEW_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<any>('');
let dataServiceFactory = (configObject):DataService => {
    return new DataService(configObject)
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [ ... ],
    declarations: [ ... ],
    providers: [
        { provide: VIEW_CONFIG, useValue: viewConfig },
        {
            provide : DataService,
            useFactory : dataServiceFactory,
            deps : [VIEW_CONFIG]
        },
    ]})
   export class Section1Module { }
```

Section file :

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(private viewConfig : any) {}

}
```

<s>**Solution 3 : custom provider with direct instanciation**</s>

***Not working after ng serve reboot (see update)***

<s>Module file :</s>

```
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import viewConfig from './view.config.json';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ ... ],
    declarations: [ ... ],
    providers: [
        { provide: DataService, useValue : new DataService(viewConfig) },
    ]})
   export class Section1Module { }
```

Section file :

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(private viewConfig : any) {}

}
```

<s>**Solution 4 : custom provider with factory**</s>

***Not working after ng serve reboot (see update)***

<s>Very similar to Solution 3...</s>

Module file :

```
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import viewConfig from './view.config.json';

let dataServiceFactory = (configObject) => { return new DataService(configObject) }

@NgModule({
    imports: [ ... ],
    declarations: [ ... ],
    providers: [
         { provide: DataService, useValue : dataServiceFactory(viewConfig) }
    ]})
   export class Section1Module { }
```

Section file :

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(private viewConfig : any) {}

}
```

**Solution 5**
Use of a factory exported from the service file AND and injection token

Module file :

```
export const VIEW_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<any>('');

 @NgModule({
    imports: [ ... ],
    declarations: [ ... ],
    providers: [
         { provide: VIEW_CONFIG, useValue: viewConfig },
         { provide : DataService,
           useFactory: dataServiceFactory,
           deps : [VIEW_CONFIG] }
    ]})
   export class Section1Module { }
```

Section file :

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor(private viewConfig : any) {}
}

export function dataServiceFactory(configObject) {
    return new DataService(configObject);
}
```

---

I'm open to any criticism, idea, new lead of any kind on "What would be the right solution ?" or even "Is the right solution among these ones ?"

Thanks a lot ! :D

---

**UPDATE**
At one point, I realised my Angular-CLI was behaving strangely, and that some of these methods weren't working if I killed my local server and did an "ng serve".
What is even stranger is, it doesn't work juste after killing the CLI local server and rebooting it, but next time I save a file and the CLI recompiles, it works fine...

**Solution 1** : still working

**Solution 2 / Solution 3** : fails with error :

```
Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 
'DataService', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the 
function or lambda with a reference to an exported function
```

**Solution 4** : fails with error:

```
Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a non-exported function
```

**Added solution 5**

Comment: The question was not my use-case but the answer point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach of using the view's config data is this:

**My config file:**

```
export const IBO_DETAILS_GENERAL = {
    iboCode: 'IBOsFormCodeField',
    iboGivenName: 'IBOsFormGivenNameField',
    iboFamilyName: 'IBOsFormFamilyNameField',
    iboEmail: 'IBOsFormEmailField',
};

export const IBO_DETAILS_ACCOUNT = [];
```

**My view component:**

```
import { IBO_DETAILS_GENERAL } from './ibo-details-formfields';

@Component({
    selector: 'ibo-details-general',
    templateUrl: './ibo-details-general.component.html',
    styles: [],
})
export class IboDetailsGeneral extends FilterDataMappingManipulator implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    // Initial constants,vectors and component mapping
    private formFields = IBO_DETAILS_GENERAL;
```

So, this way, I have my `config` in `formFields`. And I can use it anywhere within this component's scope.

I am currently using this for generating dynamic form fields (input, select, etc.) depending on which data I get from my API call.

But you can use that object (`formFields` in my case) to look for what you need and send it to your service as a parameter.

Also, good job on putting the shared service on a higher level. I believe is the best approach. But I would not add it to `providers` on each component, I would add it on the component's module. Like this:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ChildComp1,
        ChildComp2
    ],
    imports: [
    ],
    providers: [
        SharedService
    ]
})
export class SectionModule {
}
```

This way, `ChildComp1` and `ChildComp2` will have access to `SharedService` without having to add it inside the component's code.

This works fine when, for example, you are defining a *User*'s section. Inside, per say, `UsersModule` you declare in `providers` your `UsersSharedService` and then in `declarations` you declare your `UsersLeftPanel` and `UsersRightPanel` *(examples)*.

**Update 1:**

Example of usage of config within service.

Immagine that the shared service has this method:

```
getData() {
  // do Stuff
  let myData = {}; // Result of the stuff we did
  this.dataSubject.next(myData);
}
```

In your component you call this like this:

```
this.myService.getData();
```

Right?

Now, remember we had our config declared? Add it to the call.

```
this.myService.getData(this.formFields);
```

And, in our service:

```
   getData(currentConfig) {
      // do Stuff depending on currentConfig obj received as parameter
      let myData = {}; // Result of the stuff we did
      this.dataSubject.next(myData);
    }
```

This way, you call `getData()` method of our shared service passing different configurations. This way, you don't have to include your service in many `providers` and you don't have to *copy/paste* the logic that handles the configuration, you have it in your shared service and, therefore, all your children have access to it.

**Update 2:**

Following your *Solution 5* approach, I think you are missing `multi: true`.

Try this:

```
export function dataServiceFactory(configObject) {
    return () => new DataService(configObject);
}

providers: [
     { provide: VIEW_CONFIG, useValue: viewConfig },
     { provide : DataService,
       useFactory: dataServiceFactory,
       deps : [VIEW_CONFIG],
       multi: true }
]})
```

The `return` in the exported function is key: `return () =>`.

This is how I have it in my project:

```
export function initConfigFactory(userConfig: UserConfig) {
    return () => userConfig.getUsersConfig();
}
```

Where `userConfig.getUsersConfig()` is a service call that gets the user's config.

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: initConfigFactory,
        deps: [UserConfig],
        multi: true
    }
]
```

This is very close to your *Solution 5*, try it out!

Comment: From what I understand, you don't need your service to have a specific config file, so you can share an instance provided in  your parent. I need my service to be instanciated separately because it will use config infos different for each submodule, so I can't provide it on top level... unless there's something else I missed...

Comment: @SophieJobez Hi! I updated my answer. Hope it's we explained, tried my best. Tell me if you find it useful! ;)

Comment: Hi ! I understand your answer (thanks for taking time !), I didn't go this way because a kind of "object paradigm" mental thing made me think it would be cleaner to instanciate my service once with all necessary config than to give to every function the parameters...

Comment: What I mean is : if I have, let's say, 10 different functions that can process my data, and each of these functions need a parameter that is always the same for this section of the app, but can change for another section and slightly alters the comportment of the service; It means every function should be called by this.service.func(configElem), configElem taken from the currentConfig of the section... It seemed like an unnecessary repetition if I could give all the config to the service at instanciation... [Anyhow I updated my original post because I missed errors in the CLI compiler]

Comment: @SophieJobez I understand. I believe that your Option 5 with the correct return of the exported function and with the `multi: true` should work just fine. Check my second update! :D

Comment: @SophieJobez I just edited my **Update 2**. Check it out and let me know if it helps! :P

Comment: Indeed I didn't knew of the `multi:true` option. For now I only have one instance so I think that's why I didn't seem to have problems running it. I think you just avoided me headaches when I'll come to creating the other views (sections) of the app, thanks !!

Comment: Anyhow : I think both answer could be used, depending on the amount of config elements... if there's a lot, multiple instanciation with method 5 would be cleaner and reduce human error during development in passing the parameters, but many instanciation of the same service could be bad practice if there's only a few config elements and then your method would definitely be better for optimization...

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! I agree with you

Comment: I get a sense that services in Angular are conceptually a very specific kind of objects that need experience to be used at full power...

Comment: @SophieJobez yes! They are very powerful indeed. Without shared services you almost have no communication between components in a complex App

Comment: Just one thing : I got the error `Value of type 'typeof DataService' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?` which disappeared when adding 'new', making it : `return () => new DataService(configObject);`

Comment: Nice! Thanks! I will updat emy answer! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to you, in hope anyone banging his head on his desk as I was will find your full answer :) !